# How to change sandbox attribute using Javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, iframe

I don't know where I am going wrong I tried to add a value in sandbox attribute using javascript but it's not working as expected.

I was trying to add a value in sandbox of an iframe using javascript but it didn't work as expected
Here's the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="hello()">

<h1>The iframe sandbox attribute</h1>

<iframe id='ikea' src="demo_iframe_sandbox_form.htm" sandbox="">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

<p>The "Submit" button will submit the form in the inline frame.</p>
<p>Since the sandbox attribute is set to an empty string (""), the submission of the form in the inline frame will be blocked.</p>
<p>Add "allow-forms" to the sandbox attribute, to allow form submission.</p>

</body>
<script>
function hello(){
const iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');

for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
    iframes[i].setAttribute('sandbox', 'allow-forms');
}
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: How this question is related to WordPress?

Comment: works for me when i try it